# Add e-mail account to outlook with powershell

Tags: email, powershell, outlook

Using powershell I know how to add an exchange mailbox to an existing account, but i can't, for the life of me, figure out how to add another e-mail account to outlook, so the user gets the "From" field selector. Any hints from the PowerShell gurus around here?

Background: We have quite a few small biz users who make use of roomboxes to have common adress books, and to send mail as "the company". For instance the info@exampel.com roombox has its full access permissions, send as permissions, and mailflow delivery options set to allow, say, 15 people in the office to reply to mail as this box.
Obviously it gets tiresome to coordinate with each user, grab their account with RDP and click-type-click in the extra account. Powershell prefered, but other automated solutions wellcome too.

Thank you :)

Comment: What kind of account? Exchange? POP3/SMTP? Or just a delegate store?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko These are also exchange accounts - Roomboxes, with adress books, calenders and everything